# Joing multiple with one master table

Tags: mysql

I have six tables- Project,Equipment,Fish,Staff and the junction tables - Project_Equipment,Project_Fish and Project_Staff.I want to retrieve Project total cost.
So, I wrote the statement like follows,

```sql
SELECT P.ProjectID, (SUM(E.EquipPrice*PE.EQuantity)+SUM(F.FishPrice*PF.FQuantity)+SUM(PS.Salary)) as ProjectCost  
FROM Equipment as E INNER JOIN Project_Equipment as PE  
ON E.EquipID=PE.EquipID  
INNER JOIN Project as P  
ON PE.ProjectID=P.ProjectID  
INNER JOIN Project_Fish as PF  
ON P.ProjectID=PF.ProjectID  
INNER JOIN Fish as F  
ON PF.FishID=F.FishID  
INNER JOIN Project_Staff as PS  
ON P.ProjectID=PS.ProjectID  
INNER JOIN Staff as S
PS.StaffID=S.StaffID  
GROUP BY ProjectID
```

But, I got the price with twice of correct amount.

Comment: Inflation sure is out of control these days.

Comment: On a more serious note; not sure if its related to your problem but you wrote `PF.Salary`. My gut tells me there is no `Salary` column in `Project_Fish`. Is that the actual query you are using? I don't see a `select` from `Staff` either.

Comment: Sorry for my typing error mistake.i store salary in Project_Staff table.but the result is still twice.

Comment: Can you show us the schema of your tables? and post some sample data with your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query will end up with a lot of duplicate results. Consider the following simpler case:

```
Table: Project
ProjectID  EQuantity
  1          1
  2          1

Table: Equipment
EquipID    EPrice
  1          1
  2          1

Table: Fish
FishID
  1
  2

Table: Project_Equipment
ProjectID  EquipID
  1          1
  1          2
  2          1
  2          2

Table: Project_Fish
ProjectID  FishID
  1          1 
  1          2
  2          1
  2          2
```

Now, let's look at the results of a `Project_Equipment` query only:

```
SELECT p.projectid, e.eprice, pe.equantity FROM project p
INNER JOIN project_equipment pe ON pe.projectid=p.projectid
INNER JOIN equipment e ON e.equipid=pe.equipid

ProjectID EPrice EQuantity
1    1    1   // a
1    1    1   // b
2    1    1   // c
2    1    1   // d
```

That's as expected; a list of the price and quantity of each piece of equipment used by each project. But what do you think will happen when we `INNER JOIN` *that* to `project_fish`? That first result has project 1 in it twice, and project 2 in it twice, so we end up with every combination of that result and `project_fish`!

```
SELECT p.projectid, e.eprice, pe.equantity, f.fishid FROM project p
INNER JOIN project_equipment pe ON pe.projectid=p.projectid
INNER JOIN equipment e ON e.equipid=pe.equipid
INNER JOIN project_fish pf ON pf.projectid=p.projectid

ProjectID EPrice EQuantity FishID
1    1    1    1   // from a above
1    1    1    2   // from a above
1    1    1    1   // from b above 
1    1    1    2   // from b above
2    1    1    1   // from c above
2    1    1    2   // from c above
2    1    1    1   // from d above
2    1    1    2   // from d above
```

This duplication will continue with every inner join. The amount your price will be off won't always be 2x, it will actually depend on the number of combinations of all your joins.

So, you can't really do what you are trying to do with this particular query. Instead you'll have to calculate the cost of each relationship separately. Then you sum all those together. You can do this by selecting each one separately and calculating the cost into a `ProjectID` and `ProjectCost` column, using `UNION` to concatenate those altogether, then once again grouping the results by `ProjectID` and summing the individual `ProjectCost` subtotals.

I explained that poorly, but think of it as subtotaling equipment, fish, and salary costs, then sticking all those subtotals into one table and summing *that*. E.g.:

```
SELECT x.projectid, SUM(x.ProjectCost) FROM 
(
    SELECT p.projectid, SUM(e.eprice * pe.equantity) ProjectCost FROM project p
    INNER JOIN project_equipment pe ON pe.projectid=p.projectid
    INNER JOIN equipment e ON e.equipid=pe.equipid
    GROUP BY p.projectid
  UNION
    SELECT p.projectid, SUM(f.fprice * pf.fquantity) ProjectCost FROM project p
    INNER JOIN project_fish pf ON pf.projectid=p.projectid
    INNER JOIN fish f ON f.fishid=pf.fishid
    GROUP BY p.projectid
  UNION
    SELECT p.projectid, SUM(s.salary) ProjectCost FROM project p
    INNER JOIN project_staff ps ON ps.staffid=p.projectid
    INNER JOIN staff s ON s.staffid=ps.staffid
    GROUP BY p.projectid
) x
GROUP BY x.projectid
```

Each of the subqueries produces a `projectid` column and a `ProjectCost` column. Run the subquery (between the parens) by itself to see the results. The outer query then adds the subtotals for the projects.

Sorry, btw, I renamed your EquipPrice and FishPrice columns to EPrice and FPrice when I was testing.

Comment: I tried your suggested statements !bro @JasonC . But I got this error     **#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias**

Comment: Oops; I tested on SQLite where subqueries don't need aliases. Edited, should be fixed now. I aliased the subquery as `x` and added table qualifiers to the outer `projectid` and `projectcost`.